# Which is the best (performance wise) way to animate PNGs on top of a GIF in Android?

Tags: android, android-animation, animated-gif

After researching for days I still cannot find a performant way to render what I need.

I have:
 - A GIF
 - A list of PNGs
 - For each frame of the GIF there is an array with: X,Y coordinates and Rotation, for each PNGs

Basically I tracked the position of each PNG for each frame of the GIF.

Now I need to render a new object, that will have the tracked PNG moving on top of the GIF, and they have to be synchronized.

Which is the best way to achieve this without splitting the GIF into frames, create a new frame and after re-rendering the entire gif?

Thank you.

Comment: use `android.graphics.Movie`

Comment: why not using JSON format? I think it's much easier and enhance the performance.

Comment: @TanveerMunir omg, JSON? what does JSON has to do with it?

Comment: yes, you can use GIF in JSON format to animate. It increases the performance.

Comment: I'm using JSON for the tracking informations. But here, the bottleneck is the actual computation used to manipulate GIF and PNGs.

Comment: `"GIF in JSON format"` - never seen such a beast....

Comment: why not Just start from JSON?

Comment: @TanveerMunir again: what does JSON have to do with any kind of animation?

Comment: @pskink so according to you which is the best way? I'm just asking regarding about JSON.

Comment: @pskink look like that android.graphics.Movie is deprecated

Comment: @TanveerMunir are you referring to this? https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android

Comment: and there is no replacement?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedImageDrawable

Comment: yes I am referring Lottie

Comment: `Movie` was deprecated in API 28 (August 6, 2018) - on the other hand `android.provider.Contacts` was deprecated in API 5 (October 26, 2009) - almost 10 years ago but still it is in the official SDK